# Compiling Fast Light Toolkit (FLTK) 2.0 to use with fastHOG

Tags: c++, gcc, image-processing, computer-vision, fltk

I'm trying to set up a library for [histograms of oriented gradients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) called [fastHOG](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/ActiveVision/Publications/prisacariu_reid_tr2310_09/prisacariu_reid_tr2310_09.html) on my Ubuntu 12.04 computer. When I try to compile the [off-the-shelf fastHOG code](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/ActiveVision/Publications/prisacariu_reid_tr2310_09/fasthoglib.tar.gz), the compiler complains that it can't find `fltk/run.h`. According to [Rahul Ashok's tutorial about fastHOG](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/grads/r/rashok6/fastHOG.html), I need to install [Fast Light Toolkit (FLTK) 2.0](http://www.fltk.org/software.php?VERSION=1.3.0&FILE=fltk/snapshots/fltk-2.0.x-alpha-r9296.tar.gz). The tutorial says that FLTK versions other than 2.0 do not work.

So, I'm trying to compile FLTK 2.0 (`svn co http://svn.easysw.com/public/fltk/fltk/trunk fltk-2.0`). When I do `make` in the `fltk-2.0` folder, I get errors like `undefined reference to 'FcInit'`.

**Any advice for how to get FLTK 2.0 to compile properly?**

Here's the full error printout that I get when building FLTK 2.0 with g++ 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
...
Linking fluid2...
../lib/libfltk2.a(Font.o):Font.cxx:function fltk::list_fonts(fltk::Font**&): error: undefined reference to 'FcInit'
../lib/libfltk2.a(Font.o):Font.cxx:function fltk::list_fonts(fltk::Font**&): error: undefined reference to 'FcPatternCreate'
../lib/libfltk2.a(Font.o):Font.cxx:function fltk::list_fonts(fltk::Font**&): error: undefined reference to 'FcObjectSetBuild'
../lib/libfltk2.a(Font.o):Font.cxx:function fltk::list_fonts(fltk::Font**&): error: undefined reference to 'FcFontList'
../lib/libfltk2.a(Font.o):Font.cxx:function fltk::list_fonts(fltk::Font**&): error: undefined reference to 'FcPatternDestroy'
../lib/libfltk2.a(Font.o):Font.cxx:function fltk::list_fonts(fltk::Font**&): error: undefined reference to 'FcPatternGetString'
../lib/libfltk2.a(Font.o):Font.cxx:function fltk::list_fonts(fltk::Font**&): error: undefined reference to 'FcFontSetDestroy'
../lib/libfltk2.a(Font.o):Font.cxx:function fltk::Font::sizes(int*&): error: undefined reference to 'FcPatternGetDouble'
../lib/libfltk2.a(Font.o):Font.cxx:function fltk::Font::sizes(int*&): error: undefined reference to 'FcFontSetDestroy'
../lib/libfltk2.a(Font.o):Font.cxx:function fltk::Font::encodings(char const**&): error: undefined reference to 'FcFontSetDestroy'
../lib/libfltk2.a(Font.o):Font.cxx:function fltk::Font::encodings(char const**&): error: undefined reference to 'FcPatternGetString'    ../lib/libfltk2.a(Image.o):Image.cxx:function figure_out_visual(): error: undefined reference to 'XRenderFindStandardFormat'
../lib/libfltk2.a(Image.o):Image.cxx:function fl_xrender_draw_image(unsigned long, fltk::PixelType, fltk::Rectangle const&, fltk::Rectangle const&): error: undefined reference to 'XRenderCreatePicture'
../lib/libfltk2.a(Image.o):Image.cxx:function fl_xrender_draw_image(unsigned long, fltk::PixelType, fltk::Rectangle const&, fltk::Rectangle const&): error: undefined reference to 'XRenderSetPictureFilter'
../lib/libfltk2.a(Image.o):Image.cxx:function fl_xrender_draw_image(unsigned long, fltk::PixelType, fltk::Rectangle const&, fltk::Rectangle const&): error: undefined reference to 'XRenderSetPictureTransform'
../lib/libfltk2.a(Image.o):Image.cxx:function fl_xrender_draw_image(unsigned long, fltk::PixelType, fltk::Rectangle const&, fltk::Rectangle const&): error: undefined reference to 'XRenderComposite'
../lib/libfltk2.a(Image.o):Image.cxx:function fl_xrender_draw_image(unsigned long, fltk::PixelType, fltk::Rectangle const&, fltk::Rectangle const&): error: undefined reference to 'XRenderComposite'
../lib/libfltk2.a(Image.o):Image.cxx:function fl_xrender_draw_image(unsigned long, fltk::PixelType, fltk::Rectangle const&, fltk::Rectangle const&): error: undefined reference to 'XRenderComposite'
../lib/libfltk2.a(Image.o):Image.cxx:function fl_xrender_draw_image(unsigned long, fltk::PixelType, fltk::Rectangle const&, fltk::Rectangle const&): error: undefined reference to 'XRenderFreePicture'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [fluid2] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last errors seem to indicate that you are missing development files for `xrender`. Try to install [them](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xrender/0.9.0-0ubuntu4) using `apt-get` (possibly `sudo apt-get install libxrender-dev` and see if it fixes those issues.

First few errors similarly indicates that you are missing development files for [this library](http://freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-devel/x102.html). Try to install `libfontconfig1-dev`

Comment: Thanks--I just gave that a try. `libxrender-dev is already the newest version`

Comment: Anything else I might want to try?

Comment: I cant think of anything else :( I expect the flags in the Makefile properly include the above 2 libraries?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but just added for completeness.  FLTK2 doesn't build out of the box.

1) The following packages are required: once you've got them, re-run configure.  There may be more as I haven't tried this on a virgin system.

- libglu1-mesa-dev
- libice-dev
- libjpeg62-dev
- libpng12-dev
- libx11-dev
- libxcursor-dev
- libxext-dev
- libxft-dev
- libxinerama-dev
- libxi-dev
- mesa-common-dev
- zlib1g-dev

2) Modify the makeinclude after it has been generated by configure (alternatively modify config.in but I haven't figured out how to do that yet).

```
LDLIBS add -lfontconfig -lXrender
GDLIBS add -lfontconfig -lXrender -lfreetype
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting -- it seems that "enough" of FLTK built successfully for fastHOG to get past its compile errors.